# HPUX atof doesn't convert string to double

Tags: c, hp-ux

I'm fetching the version number of an hpux machine and trying to convert it to a float using atof, but this happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        struct utsname u;
        uname(&u);
        char* release = u.release;
        while (*release != '.')
                release++;
        release++;
        printf("%s\n", release);
        printf("%f\n", atof(release));
}
```

prints this:

```
# ./test
11.31
0.000000
```

Returning double 0 just means the conversion failed. The utsname man page says the strings are null terminated, so I don't understand why the atof command is failing. Am I making some kind of obvious mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `atof` function is declared in `<stdlib.h>`.

If you call it without the required `#include <stdlib.h>`, the most likely result is that (a) your compiler will print a warning (which you've apparently ignored), and (b) the compiler will assume that `atof` returns an `int` result.

Add

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to the top of your source file.  And pay attention to compiler warnings.  If you didn't get a warning, find out how to invoke your compiler in a way that makes it warn about this kind of thing. <strike>(I don't know what compiler you're using, so I can't offer specifics.)</strike> For gcc, the compiler you're using, the `-Wall` option will enable this warning.

Some background:

Prior to the 1999 edition of the ISO C standard, it was permitted to call a function with no visible declaration. The compiler would *assume* that the function takes arguments of the (promoted) types passed in the call, and that it returns a result of type `int`. This typically would work correctly if the function actually does return an `int`, and if you write the call correctly (and if the function is not variadic, like `printf`).

The 1999 version of the standard ("C99") dropped the "implicit `int`" rule, making any call to a function with no visible declaration a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic (which can be a non-fatal warning). Many compilers, will merely warn about the error and then handle the call under the older rules. And gcc still doesn't enforce C99 rules by default; its default dialect is "GNU90", consisting of the 1990 ISO C standard plus GNU-specific extensions. You can ask it to use C99 semantics with "-std=c99"; to *enforce* those semantics, you can use "-std=c99 -pedantic" or "-std=c99 -pedantic-errors".

Newer versions of gcc (partially) support the latest 2011 standard if you specify "-std=c11".

See [the gcc 4.8.2 manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Standards.html) for details.

Comment: I'm compiling with gcc. You're exactly right. I'm surprised I didn't get a warning. Adding the header fixed the problem.

Comment: @David: when using gcc, you need to get into the habit of ALWAYS using `-Wall`

Comment: Ok. If I pass -Wall into gcc, I get a warning indicating that problem. Thanks. I'll remember that for the future.